# Python Segmentation fault in numpy multiarray

Tags: python, numpy, virtualenv

I am trying to run a python script in a virtual environment. It returns a Segmentation Fault and when running gdb, it returns the segmentation fault inside numpy multiarray.so

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff347be20 in PyArray_API () from /home/jeremy/anaconda/envs/cops_and_robots/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so
```

I uninstalled and reinstalled numpy from the virtual env but the error remains. This one is confusing because there shouldn't be any problem with this official package.

Python 2.7, Numpy 1.11.0

Comment: Multi-dimensional arrays can get large really quickly. You might have just run out of memory.

Comment: Add some relevant information like your version of python, version of numpy, whether SEGV happens when you import numpy or after

Comment: Python 2.7, Numpy 1.11.0, the seg fault happens after the import

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which turned out to be a conflict between scipy and another package (pybel).  Same message from gdb as you had.  Importing numpy before anything else solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with qgis segfaulting on startup (as long as the qgis-python package is also installed) on CentOS 7 for many months. The debugger showed the same error from multiarray.so in my numpy package. Following the previous reply, I removed my scipy package (scipy-0.12.1-3.el7.x86_64), and it solved the problem. I reinstalled scipy, as an experiment. The problem did not return.